# How to make a for loop var with a string that increments in js

Tags: javascript

```
something like: for(var i="string 1"; i<10; i++){
i="string 2"
i="string 3"
}
```

and so on. Is it possible? Because I'm trying to store different things into the local storage using a for loop and i want each thing to start with a different key other than all being number indexes for easier extraction

Comment: It's totally unclear what your intention is -- neither the code nor the description help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    var string_to_store = "string " + i;
    /* store string_to_store to localStorage */
}
```

Comment: No it's absolutely fine, plus one.

Comment: That's rather obvious. It's down to the programmer to do something with the intermediate values of `string_to_store`.

Comment: It's totally wrong to place a variable and use it from outside the loop, as OP wanted to use localStorage...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - The assumption is that the OP would do whatever he wanted to do _inside_ the loop. Also, the OP's original piece of code would do nine values only ;)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript supports `+` as a way of *concatenating* a string with something else. So you can do something along the lines of

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    var s = "string " + i;
```

`s` will have the value `string 1`, `string 2`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
 console.log("string " + i);//logs to the console: string 0, string 1,..string 9
}
```